# How to stop an animation and start a new animation right after?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have the case, where the connect button is pressed, and continuously animated until the VPN has connected. Then I would like to stop the animation and load up a new set of images and animate that only once.

```
@IBOutlet weak var vpnButton: UIImageView!
var premiumImages: [UIImage] = []
var loadingImages: [UIImage] = []


@objc private func vpnStatusDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        let nevpnconn = notification.object as! NEVPNConnection
        let status = nevpnconn.status
        switch status {
        case NEVPNStatus.connecting:
            self.animateImages(imageView: self.vpnButton, images: loadingImages, duration: 1.0, isInfinite: true)
            self.vpnButton.image = UIImage(named: "Red-1")
}
```

The method that takes care of animation:

```
func animateImages(imageView: UIImageView, images: [UIImage], duration: Double, isInfinite: Bool=false) {
        imageView.stopAnimating()
        imageView.animationImages = images
        imageView.animationDuration = duration
        if !isInfinite {
            imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        } else {
            imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0
        }
        imageView.startAnimating()
    }
```

So whenever I call this, it would stop any existing animation in place and animate it with new images.

And once the VPN has connected:

```
case NEVPNStatus.connected:
     self.vpnButton.highlightedImage = UIImage(named: "OrangePressed")
     self.animateImages(imageView: self.vpnButton, images: premiumImages, duration: 0.25)
     self.vpnButton.image = UIImage(named: "OrangePremium-3")
```

Only the `loadingImages` get properly animated.  The second set `premiumImages` doesn't animate and only shows the last frame.

I suspect that stopAnimating() takes some time to accomplish, and ideally, I needed a completion handler here to know when to kick off the `imageView.startAnimating()`.

Comment: imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations() ?

Comment: Thanks, just tried it. No effect. Same problem.

Comment: What does startAnimating() do?

Comment: It’s part of iOS framework. Every UIInageView has it. You can pass in an array of uiimages and it would animate through them like an old fashion cartoon.